# Anaconda - cannot change active environment

Tags: anaconda

I want to change active environment to `cassandra` but `conda activate` command seems to not work:

```
PS C:\Users\kordi\edek> conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
                         C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
base                  *  C:\Users\kordi\anaconda3
cassandra                C:\Users\kordi\anaconda3\envs\cassandra

PS C:\Users\kordi\edek> conda activate cassandra
PS C:\Users\kordi\edek> conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
                         C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
base                  *  C:\Users\kordi\anaconda3
cassandra                C:\Users\kordi\anaconda3\envs\cassandra
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found solution to this problem.
Conda must be first initialized for use with powershell with:

```
conda init powershell
```